# CLLocationManager startMonitoringVisits is not working in simulator

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

I'm initializing visit monitoring as

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringVisits];
```

but this function never gets called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
               didVisit:(CLVisit *)visit
```

If I replace the initialize call with

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

then the same delegate starts receiving this call

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I'm using an iOS 8 simulator and simulating the location using the different debug options like freeway drive, biking and even tried setting several custom locations after waiting for a few minutes each.

I've verified the location settings and those look correct. The location manager is saved in a strong reference.

Comment: Maybe visit monitoring doesn't work on the simulator. Lots of things don't work on the simulator. It's a simulator! Try it on the device instead.

Comment: did you get any success in startMonitoringVisits: ?? How do we can test it?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work in simulator but it works on a device. I have, however, noticed that it takes time (several hours or visits to multiple locations) before the callbacks are triggered.

Answer (score 1):

This feature cannot work in the simulator, because in addition to just "Location" monitoring (via GPS, WiFi, Cell network, Proximity sensors, BlueTooth spots etc. - most of which do not exist in the simulator) it also employs lots of heuristics and logic, to determine what a "Visit" is.

e.g. - you need to "move" to a new place. Then "stay" there for some time (of course your location readouts vary all the time). You then must "leave" - move away from that place for at least some time and distance, to create a "visit".

These things do not happen at the simulator, hence - no visits there.

If you visit Ray Wenderlich's site, there's a tutorial there which demonstrates the use of CLVisit, and applies a nice method to "Fake" visits to the simulator, via another API + GPTX resource file (a route of GPS locations and times, fed to the simulator).